# Writing a handler to figure out the type of data in a resultset

Tags: java, mysql, resultset

So, I have a program written in java that looks at a mysql database, and I have a few queries that run against it in different parts of the program.

In dealing with the resultset that populates during a select / leftjoin statement, I've found it to be very cumbersome.  In example, what if I didn't know the exact type of data that was in the table?   Is there any (good) way to write a handler that will cast an int to an int / a double to a double, String to a string... on and on.

I just wonder because I feel like doing a resultset > String > Double is very inefficient Double.parseDouble((resultset.getString(index))); just feels wrong because it means that I have to know not only the datatype, but the exact indexing.   This also makes nulls a bit more tricky too.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's usually helpful to work out your algorithms first and do your optimizing second. Compared to the network IO and disk IO time for retrieving rows, getString is pretty cheap.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the JDBC class called ResultSetMetaData.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

There's a nice method called `getColumnType (int colnum)`.